# Can I get a jQuery Deferred on document.ready()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Right after my script is loaded I am making an Ajax request to get some translations. This should always return after the document is ready since I am loading my scripts at the bottom of the page, but I am still curious if it would be possible to get a [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) on the document ready state.

That way it would be possible to make sure that both, the document is ready and the Ajax call returned successfully before doing anything else, e.g. like this:

```
$.when( $.ajax('translations'), document.ready())
.then(function(){
    // Start doing stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can associate a deferred object with the document using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), and [resolve()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) it in your `ready` handler. This way, you should be able to use the stored deferred object with [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

```
$(document).data("readyDeferred", $.Deferred()).ready(function() {
    $(document).data("readyDeferred").resolve();
});

$.when($.ajax("translations"), $(document).data("readyDeferred"))
 .then(function() {
    // Start doing stuff here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and straightforward. That will probably also work with a global variable or something similar.

Comment: @Daff, absolutely. I personally prefer using `data()` instead of a global variable because it's more flexible and avoids polluting the global namespace.

Comment: Pedantic note.  There's no reason to store the variable at all.  You only need it during setup phase, so use closure scope: `(function() { var deferred = new $.Deferred(); $(function() { deferred.resolve(); }); $.when($.ajax('foo'), deferred).then(function() {}); })();`...  If you use local scopes, there's no need to store, just let the closures bind it for you...

Answer (score 21):

Here's a cleaned up version of ircmaxell's comment:

```
(function() {
  var doc_ready = $.Deferred();
  $(doc_ready.resolve);
  $.when(doc_ready, $.ajax('translations')).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
  });
})();
```

**edit**

Some clarification to stop the incorrect edits:

Passing a function to the jquery object (e.g. `$(some_func)`) is the same as `$(document).ready(some_func)`.

Therefore, the `$(doc_ready.resolve);` line is just shorthand for something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  doc_ready.resolve()
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
$.when($.ajax('translations'), $.ready).then(function() {
    // Start doing stuff here
});
```

Comment: Note that `$.ready` is not in fact a deferred, but happens to have a `promise` method anyway.

Comment: No, it's not yet been documented: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/205

Answer (score 6):

My version is:

```
$.when(
  $.Deferred(function() { $(this.resolve); }), 
  $.ajax('translations')).
  then(function() { console.log("done"); });
```

Comment: I like the way the deferred is contained.  
One suggestion would be to change to order of your deferreds, so that your callback function first argument would be any value that was resolved for the $.ajax deferred.

Answer (score 2):

*Update for reference (2015):*

This is available in current versions of jQuery:

```js
$.when($.ready).then(...);
```

It is also simple to convert to a stream using [highlandjs](http://highlandjs.org):

```js
_($.when($.ready)).map(transform).pipe(output) // etc.
```

Comment: As it was mentioned earlier it's not documented that $.ready is a deferred like object. This is still undocumented in 2016.

Comment: There is something about that in this link: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ready/#jQuery-ready1

Comment: Yes, this has been added to the documentation as of March 2017

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `when` is not a proper promise. You can force it into one like this:

```
function documentReady() {
    return Promise.resolve($.when($.ready));
}
```

Usage:

```
documentReady().then(function($) { ... });
```

It happens to resolve with `$` so that's kind of convenient too.

Alternative implementation:

```
function documentReady() {
    return new Promise(r => $(r));
}
```