# How can I fire jQuery outside document.ready block?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The common method of starting jQuery is putting it in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all jQuery stuff here
});
```

But what if I have a complicated site which uses basic jQuery in `<head>` **and** some custom functions that depend on the page type (e.g. if I have login page, fire some login ajax stuff).

So, how can I attach code to `$(document).ready()` **or** fire it later? Which JS syntax should I use?

Thanks for help!

---

My page structire is similar to this:

1. Display **static** header using PHP's `include()`
2. Add content inside `<body></body>`
3. Display the template footer

---

```
<?php

include_once('system/classes/class.display.php');

$d = new IFDisplay();

$d->display_header(array('subtitle' => 'Log In')); <-- Here it displays static
                                                       head tags. There is
                                                       document.ready in there.
                                                       I can't change it.

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
AND WHAT DO I NEED TO PUT HERE
</script>

<div>...</div>

<?php

$d->display_footer();

?>
```

Comment: Give us a specific example of what you want to do and we can help.  Your question is way too general.  jQuery is just javascript.  You only need to put it in `$(document).ready()` if the javascript code requires waiting for the DOM to be loaded.  Also, you can use multiple `$(document).ready()` calls and you can put them anywhere.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want your code to run when the DOM becomes ready, or when an AJAX request completes, whichever occurs last. If that's indeed the case, [Can I get a jQuery Deferred on document.ready()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6177187/464709) might interest you.

Comment: I mean, what if I put it before, and I want to add some other things *later*?

Comment: @Kashiv: What do you mean by "add things later"?

Comment: @Kashiv - if you want to go for something modular the $(function(){}) method is the most robust in terms of code collisions, if you think someone else might be using your javascript, etc.  If you have control over the entire page, then you can certainly include the javascript at the bottom.  In the event you can't control that, see my answer below.

Comment: @Kashiv: What do you want the script to do?  Show us the "basic jQuery in `<head>`".

Comment: Voting to close as this question is completing unclear as to what it is asking.

Comment: @Kashiv: You can have multiple `$(document).ready(function(){` on a page.  They will run in the order they were added.

Comment: My question is very simple: is there a way to fire jQuery (e.g. `$('a.someclass').click()` **outside `$(document).ready()`** block?

Comment: @Kashiv: Yes, put the code outside the `$(document).ready()` block.

Comment: what do you mean by "fire" jQuery .click()?  the .click() is a listener function used like this:
$('a.someclass').click(function(){// do stuff}) and can only be fired when a user clicks, which is after the document is ready anyway?  the docready function will fire when it's called if the document is already set up.

Comment: OK, people, that's what I asked about. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't worried about race conditions, you should be able to use this:

```
$(function(){
    //put your code here
});
```

As many times as you like.

Comment: `$(function(){` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: agreed, just putting the shorthand out there because it's less code.  Probably should have explained that, sorry

Comment: This is exactly right - you can do this as many times as you want, and all of them will trigger once the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Shane, what race conditions are you referring to? `ready` handlers run sequentially in registration order, not in parallel.

Comment: I took the reference to the head as a red flag, meaning he might want to reference specific elements before the DOM is created, etc.  If that's the case then you'd want to go another route.

Comment: Your answer doesn't answer the question

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson The question as I understood it (7 years ago) was how to fire jQuery based code contingent on the document being loaded without necessarily firing at the point of the document loading or conflicting with the call in the head.  This worked at the time.  When you say the answer isn't relevant, has jQuery changed (I no longer use it) or is your question different from what I believe to be the OP?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a block of code that you want to be able to run BOTH in a `$(document).ready()` function and sometime later like when an ajax call completes, then you can just define a function and call it both places like this:

```
// define this in the global scope or some other publicly available scope (not inside a document.ready() call).
function myOperation() {
   // put your code here
}

$(document.ready(function() {
    myOperation();
});
```

And, then sometime later (like in an ajax call in your other code), you can call that same function with this:

```
myOperation()
```