# Do JQuery.ajax call immediately, but not call callbacks until document.ready?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, deferred

I am using jQuery and currently doing an `$.ajax()` call inside the `$(document).ready()` function. However I realized that to do the AJAX call I do not use anything from the DOM. Also that Ajax call might take a second or two (or more) server-side. So, for both those reasons, I'd like to get it going as soon as possible, and I'm thinking to refactor my code to look something like this (this would go in a `<script>` block near the top of the HTML file):

```
var someGlobal="whatever";
...
function onReply(response){
  //Do something
}
...
$.ajax({
   'url':"call_me.json",
   'type':'POST',
   'data':{x:someGlobal,y:"Dude!"}
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR,status){
    console.log("AJAX ERROR:" + status);
    })
  .done(onReply);
...
```

However, the `onReply()` callback *does* need the DOM to have been constructed (ditto for the `.fail()` callback). So I don't want `onReply` to be called before `$(document).ready()` has run. Is there anything built-in to jQuery that allows me to guarantee that will be the case?

P.S. Using jQuery 1.10.x

Comment: Very similar question (once you think to use deferreds): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177187/can-i-get-a-jquery-deferred-on-document-ready  (but none of the answers consider what happens if the ajax call fails; they also don't start the ajax call until the page has fully loaded, and I want to start it immediately.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var flag = 0;
function onReply(response){
    if (flag == 0)
    {
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                anotherfunction(response);
            });
    }
    else
        anotherfunction(response);
}

$(document).ready(
    function () {
        flag = 1;
    }
);

function anotherfunction(resp) {
    // Do something
}
```

**Better way (1.5 years later):**
Instead of using a variable to track the load status of the `document`, we can use the javascript's own `document.readyState`.

```
function onReply(response){
    function ProcessResponse() {
        // Do something with 'response'
    }
    document.readyState == 'complete' ? ProcessResponse() : $(ProcessResponse);
}
```

Comment: @Ramesh: Your doubt is absolutely right. See I have updated the answer.

Comment: Does this code contain a race condition, or are JavaScript methods never interrupted / pre-empted?

Comment: @Zack By what I understand about a race condition, this is not one. Since the main event takes place only after both the required events have taken place. And I don't think javascript methods are interrupted ever.

Answer (score 0):

I recently read [Learning jQuery Deferreds](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030508.do) and I believe this is the elegant solution I was looking for, a couple of months ago, when I posted this question!

To use it, I create a global `Deferred` object, which is `resolve()`-ed when the DOM is ready. From that `Deferred` object, I extract a promise, and the `$.ajax()` call returns a promise. I don't want `onReply()` (or the ajax error handling) called until both those actions have completed, or in Deferred jargon, until both the promises have been resolved. The way we do that is using `$.when()`, which takes a list of promises(*) to wait for, and returns another promise object, to which we can attach the `fail()` and `done()` handlers.

*: Technically they do not need to be promise objects; they can be normal functions too.

Here is a first draft of that solution:

```
var someGlobal = 'whatever';
var readyToInit = $.Deferred();
...
function onReply(response){
  //Do something
}
...
var ajaxPromise = $.ajax({
   'url':'call_me.json',
   'type':'POST',
   'data':{x:someGlobal,y:'Dude!'}
  });

$.when( ajaxPromise, readyToInit.promise() )
  .fail(function(jqXHR,status){
    console.log('AJAX ERROR:' + status);
    })
  .done(onReply);
...
$(function() {  //OnReady
    readyToInit.resolve();  //Anything waiting for the page to load can go now
});
```